# Highcharts Highmaps the data does not match with polygons correctly

Tags: highcharts

I built a map with Highmaps: see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Joh_Christ/Luk9eyt4/3/)

The data comes from this [google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/105jszNGYP9P8g5mnmPY2wZgofnayy8TPZM2RBKYTf-c/edit#gid=1752069242)

see code:

```
  data: {
googleAPIKey: 'AIzaSyB-ZvAYEcpvptgn77Mfld0iHwSRAVepo7I',
googleSpreadsheetKey: '105jszNGYP9P8g5mnmPY2wZgofnayy8TPZM2RBKYTf-c',
seriesMapping: [{
  'land': 0,
  'inzidenz': 1,
  'value': 1,
  'hc-key': 2,
  'lat': 3,
  'lon': 4
},{
  'land': 0,
  'inzidenz': 1,
  'value': 1,
  'hc-key': 2,
  'lat': 3,
  'lon': 4,
  'z': 1
}],
complete: function(options) {
  options.series[0].name = 'Inzidenz';
  options.series[1].name = 'Labels';
}},
```

But the data is not displayed on the correct polygons, e.g. the value of Hessen in Bayern etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is a Highmaps regression bug: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/16782

As a workaround, you can add an empty point on init:

```
  series: [{
    type: 'map',
    data: [{}],
    ...
  }, ...]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/edpbjvm1/

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are using `mapbubble` instead of `map` as your `series.type`?

If you change it to map, it works.

https://jsfiddle.net/vf8o7cnd/1/

Comment: The Labels are the labels of invisible bubbles. I want to control their position. Otherwise they overlap on small screens. And the data still does not fit to the polygons.